# Is there a semi-permanent way to attach wires to the Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, prototype, wires

At least for prototyping, is there a semi-permanent way to attach wires to the Nano posts?

[image: Arduino nano]

And yes, usually the Nano is hanging in free space by its wires (yes I know, quick and dirty, should be using something cleaner, even for prototypes).  So I'm hoping for the best of both worlds, sturdy "enough" to stay attached, yet possible to remove and switch around.  Having no luck finding such advice on the internet, perhaps searching for the wrong terms.

**EDIT:**  I neglected one important point, each wire is attached individually just like the SparkFun wires with the female header as mentioned in @TheDoctor's answer below.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for.  Dupont connector, maybe?

Comment: What about a breadboard? They're useful so the wires are a little more secure.

Comment: Don't forget about soldering. It is a time proven semipermanent to permanent way of attaching wires.

Comment: You are trying to do something in a harder and less effective manner than you could be. Yes, there are ways of doing what you want. No, it is almost certain that not using a breadboard makes sense. There may be constraints which make various solutions unsuitable but, if so, you should include them in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are jumper wires that have a female header on one end and a male header on the other. Example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9140

[image: jumper wires]

You could also attatch several wired to a strip of breakaway female headers, such as https://www.sparkfun.com/products/115

[image: headers]

Comment: The row of female headers, shown in the second link, is the way to go, since the individual wires have a tendency to pop out every now and then, whereas the entire row is much more secure.

Answer (score 2):

A wire wrap tool can work well for this - the wrappings tend to be fairly secure if done right, though the wire itself can break if stressed.

Answer (score 2):

The *entire* premise behind Gravitech's design of the Arduino Nano was for it to be plugged into a **breadboard**. If done so, then none of the pins are left *dangling*. From [Arduino's webpage for the Nano](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano):

> The Arduino Nano is a small, complete, and *breadboard-friendly* board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.x) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has more or less the same functionality of the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks only a DC power jack, and works with a Mini-B USB cable instead of a standard one. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.

From [Gravitech's webpage for the Nano](http://www.gravitech.us/arna30wiatp.html):

> Arduino Nano is a surface mount *breadboard* embedded version with
>   integrated USB. It is a smallest, complete, and *breadboard friendly*.
>
> ...
>
> Nano’s got the *breadboard-ability* of the Boarduino and the Mini+USB
>   with smaller footprint than either, so users have more *breadboard*
>   space.

If you have a Nano in such a *dangling* state, then you are using the wrong sort of Arduino board for the wrong purpose.

Obviously a Nano will work just fine when *loose* on a surface, i.e. not plugged into a breadboard, but that is not what it was intended for, and maybe you should employ an UNO in its place.

However, if you have to use your Nano without a breadboard, then in addition to the wire wrapping, wires with female DuPont connectors, or female header strips, you could just solder wires to the holes in the nano board, if you do not already have header pins already soldered in to them.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's what I use](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-NANO-3-0-controller-Terminal-Adapter-for-NANO-terminal-expansion-board-for-arduino-Nano/1921109123.html), repeatedly, successfully. It fits the Nano headers, and gives you screw terminals for proto work.

Comment: Ooh! that's pretty.